# MySQL ORDER BY issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to do too much maybe in one SQL statement. I'd like to get sub-totals and a grand-total all in the appropriate places in the output table. This is my SQL;

```
SELECT Date, DOW, Week, Year, logdate, Month, monum, netID, Logins, 
       creds, newb, netCnt, TOD, netCnt, activity
  FROM (SELECT logdate
              ,activity
              ,DATE( logdate )                      AS Date
              ,DAYOFWEEK( logdate )         AS DOW
              ,WEEK( logdate,0 )              AS Week
              ,YEAR( logdate )              AS Year
              ,DATE_FORMAT( logdate, '%M' )         AS Month
              ,DATE_FORMAT( logdate, '%m' )     AS monum
              ,CONVERT( netID,UNSIGNED INTEGER )    AS netID
              ,COUNT( callsign )                    AS Logins
              ,COUNT( IF(creds <> '',1,NULL) )  AS creds
              ,COUNT( IF(comments LIKE '%first log in%',1,NULL) ) AS newb
              ,count( DISTINCT netID )      AS netCnt
              ,SUM(  DISTINCT netID)            AS allCnt
              ,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(timeonduty) )       AS TOD
         FROM NetLog
        WHERE netID <> 0 
          AND activity NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
          AND netcall LIKE '%W0KCN%'
          AND substr(logdate,1,4) = 2017
    GROUP BY Month, netID WITH ROLLUP ) AS t 
    ORDER BY t.logdate , logins
```

The (abbreviated) output looks like this;
[image: Output of Query]

You'll notice that each month is ordered correctly until you get to October. The grand total gets sorted before October instead of at end (after December). Is this something I can control in the SQL or should I fix this in PHP? How would I fix it in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed a CASE statement to get this working.

```
SELECT Date, DOW, Week, Year,  Month, monum, netID, Logins, 
       creds, newb, netCnt, TOD, activity, logdate,
       COALESCE (Month, 'GT') as MonthNM
  FROM (SELECT logdate
              ,activity
              ,DATE( logdate )                      AS Date
              ,DAYOFWEEK( logdate )                 AS DOW
              ,WEEK( logdate,0 )                    AS Week
              ,YEAR( logdate )                      AS Year
              ,MONTHNAME ( logdate )                AS Month
              ,MONTH( logdate )                     AS monum
              ,CONVERT( netID,UNSIGNED INTEGER )    AS netID
              ,COUNT( callsign )                    AS Logins
              ,COUNT( IF(creds <> '',1,NULL) )      AS creds
              ,COUNT( IF(comments LIKE '%first log in%',1,NULL) ) AS newb
              ,count( DISTINCT netID )              AS netCnt
              ,SUM(  DISTINCT netID)                AS allCnt
              ,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(timeonduty) )       AS TOD
         FROM NetLog
        WHERE netID <> 0 
          AND activity NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
          AND netcall LIKE '%W0KCN%'
          AND substr(logdate,1,4) = 2017
    GROUP BY Month, netID WITH ROLLUP ) AS t 
    ORDER BY 
     CASE
        WHEN MonthNM = 'GT' THEN  1
        ELSE 0
     END
        ,monum
        ,logins
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second field `logins` will be sorted  accordingly only within equal values of the firs sorted column. Otherwise, sorting priority on the first column. Try to swap `logdate` and `logins` and see what's happen.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean when you say "swap logdate and logins". Where should I swap them?